# How can I add multiple series to a chart in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, chart, scatterplot

I am using ArcGIS Pro version 2.5.0. I want to create multiple scatter plots, but where they are all graphed on the same figure. That is, I have three different cities where I want to plot the same variable (y-axis) against income (x-axis) in each of those cities and to have a per-city regression line.

The option to have multiple series in a single chart is available in ArcGIS (at least in version 10.7.1, the one I am using) under view-->graphs-->create graphs-->add-->new series. However, as far as I can tell this option is not available in ArcGIS Pro.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that functionality exists in ArcPro, you could try using a [scatter plot matrix](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/charts/scatter-plot-matrix.htm)?

Otherwise get yourself over to the geonet website and suggest it as an [idea](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/) for an improvement, don't ask don't get...